# C freeing pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

In my code, I have several pointers to pointers (e.g. float ** variables), and I seem to be having issues freeing up their memory so as to not cause memory leaks. Here is the code that I have written:

```
float *one, **part1, **part2;

one = malloc(sizeof(&one) * nx * nx);
part1 = malloc(sizeof(&part1) * nx);

if(one == NULL || part1 == NULL) {
 printf("Memory error.\n");
 exit(2);
}

for(k = 0; k < nx; k++)
 part1[k] = &one[k * nx];

one = malloc(sizeof(&one) * nx * nx);
part2 = malloc(sizeof(&part2) * nx);

if(one == NULL || part2 == NULL) {
 printf("Memory error.\n");
 exit(2);
}

for(k = 0; k < nx; k++)
 part2[k] = &one[k * nx];

... (Other code here)

for(k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
 free(part1[k]);
 free(part2[k]);
}

free(one);
free(part1);
free(part2);
```

This code runs through, does the calculations correctly, but then errors out in the free loop. It works for k = 0, but then when trying to free part1[1] and part2[1], it gives me the "glibc detected" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
one = malloc(sizeof(&one) * nx * nx);
part1 = malloc(sizeof(&part1) * nx);
```

These should be

```
one = malloc(sizeof(*one) * nx * nx);
part1 = malloc(sizeof(*part1) * nx);
```

You want to allocate a bunch of `float`s and `float *`s, not `float **`s and `float ***`s

Secondly, you make 4 allocations -- you allocate `one`, and indices into it in `part1`,
and allocate `one` again, (forgetting the old address), and indices into it in `part2`.

This means you should have 4 `free()`s: `part1`, `part2`, and both chunks of memory to which `one` pointed.  Because you overwrite the first `one`, you've lost that pointer and can't directly `free()` it.  Fortunately you did save that pointer in `part1[0]`, and can use that to `free()` all the memory pointed to.

Another (perhaps clearer and more idiomatic) option would be to allocate differently.  Allocate `part1`, and then loop to allocate each `part1[k]`, and the same for `part2`.

Comment: I didn't want to do this because the memory would then not be contiguous, correct? I believe this would cause some loss in efficiency. Obviously, working inefficiently is better than not working at all, but I was just trying to make it work like this. Also, I save the pointer to one in more than just part1[0], right? My first loop saves the pointer in part1[k] as k goes from 0 to nx, which is why I tried to free the same amount of memory.

Comment: "My first loop saves the pointer in part1[k] as k goes from 0 to nx".  No, you save _offsets_ from one.  &one[0] = one.  &one[k] = one + k.  free(one) frees the whole lump of memory, as would free(part1[0]);

Answer (score 1):

You have only 4 `malloc` calls, so you should only have 4 `free` calls. You never allocated anything in a loop, so why are you freeing in a loop?

`part1[k]` and `part2[k]` were never allocated by themselves, they just point to an area of the memory allocated to `one`, so you should just free `one`. Also, you have a memory leak here:

```
one = malloc(sizeof(&one) * nx * nx);
part1 = malloc(sizeof(&part1) * nx);

...

// *** You just lost the previous old pointer here *** //
one = malloc(sizeof(&one) * nx * nx);
part2 = malloc(sizeof(&part2) * nx);
```

The reason your code works for `k = 0` is because `part1[0] == &one[0] == one`, i.e. `part1[0]` actually points to the beginning of the `one` block -- by freeing this, you are freeing the entire block.

And I'm not sure what your `sizeof` means. I'm guessing you wanted to allocate `nx * nx` floats -- if so, that should be `sizeof(*one)` -- `*one` is a float, but `&one` is the address of `one`, which is a `float **` pointer.

---

You really want to be doing something like this:

```
one1 = malloc(sizeof(*one) * nx * nx);
part1 = malloc(sizeof(*part1) * nx);

...

for(k = 0; k < nx; k++)
 part1[k] = &one1[k * nx];

...

free(part1);
free(one1);
```

Comment: That was my first attempt, but it was giving me memory leaks (i.e. after a few hours of repeated looping, it was taking up over 10gb of memory, which is far too large when nx is only 16).

Comment: @wolfPack88: Did you consider the possible leak that I mentioned above, i.e. did you have separate two separate `one` blocks and free them both?

Comment: I did not, but I was not certain that would cause a memory leak... If I store the one pointer in part1, then free part1, there should be no memory leak, correct? Or am I misunderstanding the way memory allocation works?

Answer (score 1):

Look at how many malloc's you're doing and how many frees you are doing.  The numbers don't match.

In general you cannot free a part of a malloc'd structure.  You can only free it all.  So at the end you want something more like:

```
... (Other code here)
/* four mallocs so four frees */
free(part1[0]);
free(part2[0]);
free(part1);
free(part2);
```